# How to choose between two tables based on conditions

Tags: mysql

Say I have 'userBasic', 'userMan', 'userWoman' table.

'userBasic' table has column called 'userNum' and 'gender'.

I am trying to retrieve data from either userMan or userWoman based on gender and userNum from userBasic table.

Simply put,

```
select A.gender, B.nickname from userBasic A, (userman or userwoman) B 
      where A.gender=? and B.userNum=A.userNum;
```

if A.gender is man --> use userman B, if not use userwoman B.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ub.gender,
    CASE
        WHEN ub.gender = 'male' THEN um.nickname
        ELSE uw.nickname
    END as nickname
FROM userBasic as ub
LEFT JOIN userMan as um ON ub.userNum = um.userNum
LEFT JOIN userWoman as uw on ub.userNum = uw.userNum
```

OR if you need to select multiple columns and dont want to do more case statements

```
SELECT 
    ub.gender, um.nickname
FROM userBasic as ub
INNER JOIN userMan as um ON ub.userNum = um.userNum
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    ub.gender, uw.nickname
FROM userBasic as ub
INNER JOIN userWoman as um ON ub.userNum = uw.userNum
```